# A question of probability regarding expectation and variance of a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, variance

> > Suppose that we have an infinite supply of balls and N boxes. Fix $k \le N$. The balls are thrown at random into the boxes until exactly $k$ boxes are occupied. Let $X$ denote the number of throws needed for this. Calculate $E(X)$ and $\mathrm {Var} (X)$.

If for $i \geq k$, $X=i$ then that implies the success is obtained in the $i$-th trial. So it means that we have exactly $(k-1)$ occupied boxes in the $(i-1)$-th trial. Then the $i$-th ball is placed at some box other than the former $(k-1)$ boxes. How can we do that?

First we choose $(k-1)$ boxes from $N$ boxes. Then we put $(i-1)$ balls into those boxes such that no box is left empty. Then the remaining $i$-th ball can be placed in any of  the remaining $(N-k+1)$ boxes.

So according to me we have for $i \geq k$

$$P(X=i) = \frac { {N \choose {k-1}}S(i-1,k-1){N-k+1\choose 1}} {N^i}.$$ Where $S(m,n)$ denotes the number of all surjective functions from an $m$ elements set onto an $n$ elements set.

But then the expressions of expectation and variance  become very complicated. Is everything I have done so far correct? If 'yes' can somebody please tell me the easier way to calculate the expectation and variance of the above random variable $X$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a variant of the [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), for $k=N$ it is literally that problem.  Similar techniques should apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The time it takes to hit a new empty box when $j$ boxes are already occupied is geometrically distributed with success probability $1-\frac jN$. These times are independent. The expectation and variance of a geometric distribution with success probability $p$ are $\frac1p$ and $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$, respectively. The expectation and variance of the sum of independent random variables are the sum of the expectations and variances, respectively. Thus

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E(X)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac1{1-\frac jN}=N\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac1{N-j}
\end{eqnarray*}

and

$$
\mathsf{Var}(X)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\frac jN}{\left(1-\frac jN\right)^2}=N\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac j{(N-j)^2}\;.
$$

Comment: Where have I done mistake @joriki?

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay.: Your "mistake" was to derive a probability distribution for a problem that asks for an expectation. (A variance is a form of expectation.) More often than not, finding an entire probability distribution is orders of magnitude more work than finding an expectation, so taking the detour through the probability distribution is usually a big waste of effort.

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay.: And this problem is a good demonstration of why this is so. You can just add the expectations and variances of the individual times of which $X$ is a sum, whereas finding the probability distribution from the probability distributions of the summands would have been a ton of work with complicated convolutions to calculate.

Comment: Is the PMF I wrote correct?

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay.: It looks right, yes, just not very useful to solve the problem at hand :-)

Comment: Ok. Thanks @joriki for your help.